# SBT test - test only files in a certain subdirectory

Tags: testing, sbt, subdirectory

Say I have a directory `all` that contains directories with subject-specific testcases, e.g. `basic`, `sets`, `issues`, ...

In sbt, I can use `test` to run all testcases in all subdirectories of `all`.

I can use `test-only -- -n TESTCASE` to only test the `TESTCASE` file. What I cannot seem to figure out, though, is what arguments I must pass to what command in order to only test all the testcases in a certain subdirectory.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`test-only` can be restricted to:

- the package structure of your test classes,
- the sbt project you have slected
- and accepts glob-style regexes

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html

You can simply put those tests in the same package, which you would need to do to reflect the package structure in your file folder structure anyway, and call `myproject/testOnly path.to.my.package`.